# jQuery Datatable is Not applying on Table : Showing Invalid Column Count instead

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have created a sample table and applied `datatable` on that table. But it is giving me error as **Invalid column count**, but my columns in header and body are same in counts. I would need to generate the table via connecting with `sql` table. Therefore, I want if table in side `Gridview` div have length greater than 0, then only `datatable` should apply. below is the code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="GridView">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Sno</th>
            <th>user</th>
            <th>delete</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Dummy Name</td>
            <td><a>Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="Scripts/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#GridView').find("table").length > 0) {
            $('#GridView').find("table").DataTable();
        }
    });
</script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to place your columns inside a `thead` tag and your data rows inside a `tbody` tag like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#GridView').find("table").length > 0) {
            $('#GridView').find("table").DataTable();
        }
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<div id="GridView">
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sno</th>
            <th>user</th>
            <th>delete</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Dummy Name</td>
            <td><a>Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```